# Bitmap size in Android programmatically Vs. ADB size

Tags: java, android, image

I have searched for this, and i found that for api less than 12, usually what is used is bitmap.getrowbytes * bitmap.getheight;

However, for an image i am obtaining the following:

```
mBitmap.getRowBytes() = 320
mBitmap.getHeight() = 100
mBitmap.getWidth() = 80.
```

Thus according to the above formula I get 32,000.

However when i check the file that i m reading the bitmap image from from adb using

```
ls -l
```

I get that the size is 90Kb.

I am reading the image as follows:

```
        Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
        if (chosenImageUri != null) {
            try {
       InputStream photoStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(chosenImageUri);
          BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
              opts.inSampleSize = 4;
              Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(photoStream,null, opts);
          photoStream.close();

} 
}
```

Why are the results different? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just understood what's going on. I will post this in case it helps anyone.

The reason of this is that I am using bitmapfactoryoptons along with insamplesize =4.

What happens is

For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1.

as mentioned [here](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/05/reduce-bitmap-by-setting-insamplesize.html)

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory an image takes on the RAM is different from the one on disk. In the RAM, the image's memory consumption can be checked by the formula `pixels*3` if it's RGB and `pixels*4` if it's ARGB. Number of pixels can be found by `width*height`. Your image must have an alpha channel, as `80*100*4 = 32,000`. Note that this is in Bytes, and to get it in kB or MB you'll need to divide that by 1024 and 1024*1024 respectively.